# async resolve() needs to be wrapped?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why do I need to wrap `resolve()` with meaningless async function in node 10.16.0, but not in chrome? Is this node.js bug?

```js
let shoot = async () => console.log('there shouldn\'t be race condition');

(async () => {
  let c = 3;
  while(c--) {

    // Works also in node 10.16.0
    // console.log(await new Promise(resolve => shoot = async (...args) => resolve(...args)));

    // Works is chrome, but not in node 10.16.0?
    console.log(await new Promise(resolve => shoot = resolve));

  };
})();

(async () => {
  await shoot(1);
  await shoot(2);
  await shoot(3);
})();
```

Comment: It might be a Node bug, yes. I don’t really like reading the ES promises spec, so not going to find out, but: relying on synchronizing specific numbers of microtasks is bad design. (Add 2 `await null`s between `shoot`s to see it work in Node 10.)

Comment: I'am not really sure about the inconsistency but as per documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await, `await` can only be used inside the async function.

Comment: @randomSoul - it is only being used inside an async function. There is no error here, just interesting order of events.

Comment: What is the point of an infinite loop that creates a promise and immediately resolves it over and over again?  You're just creating an inordinate amount of load on the CPU and trying to see which Javascript engines will give something else enough cycles to run.  It seems like a useless test to me.  All event loops in all Javascript engines are not identical (no surprise).  Write code that doesn't need to have the event loop work exactly one way.

Comment: What does not working mean? What happens in node 10.16.0 ?

Comment: I find these tests that write really, really bad code and then wonder why it doesn't work everywhere to be a total waste of time.  They aren't real.  Nobody should ever write code this way!  If you're trying to diagnose one particular part of the event loop logic, then ask a question about that in particular.

Comment: This code makes no sense. If you're going to await `shoot()`, you should declare it as `async`. And using `while(1) {...}` anywhere is really bad code, never do that, not even for demonstration purposes. Can you instead explain what you're trying to do, so that maybe people can help you write the code to do that?

Comment: @jfriend00 the code probably only seems weird because he made a good ***minimal*** reducible example. Exporting the resolve function to an outer scope is a little weird, but it has its uses, in this case he is using it to create something like a generator, (calling `shoot()` does one iteration and yields a value).

Comment: @Paulpro, in node, it will show just the first one and then exit. The other calls for `shoot()` will not trigger the `await` in the endless loop and will resolve again the same promise (first one)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've edited so it will not be endless loop. Also, endless loops have their place in high performance/low latency systems, usually not in javascript.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans without the `await` in `await shoot()` (even without wrapping it in `async`) it does not work - only 1 resolves.

Comment: @jfriend00, the infinite loop that was there does not create any cpu load. As it only runs 3 times and than waits there forever, no cpu will be used beyond the 3 cycles. However, I do agree it is not necessary to be infinite.

Comment: @Ry- Thank you. This is probably what is happening here.

Comment: @niry no, you are much misunstanding how async/await work together. You _await_ and _async_ function's return value. So if you use `await` with a function that isn't `async`, you're not awaiting anything, you're just running code synchronosouly, which is the standard JS execution model. The `await` _does nothing_ except when the function call it's for is an `async` function. In this case, you're showing a `let shoot = () => ...` which is a _synchronous_ function, it doesn't have `async`, you can't `await` it, it's already synchronous.

Comment: So again: _what are you trying to do_ that made you try writing this code, because async/await is not hard, but it does require understanding that under the hood, you're awaiting a promise resolution, and that if you write an async function, you're _generating_ a promise, so anything "more than basic async/await" ends up as you writing code involving `Promise.all`, `Promise.race`, `Promise.allSettled`, etc. which I strongly suspect is the case here. Your triple `await shoot` suggests that what you really wanted is `Promise.all`, because otherwise you wouldn't use `await`, you'd just call shoot

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I perfectly understand how async/await works... that is not the question here. The `let shoot = () => ...` is relevant since it is being overwritten way before it is called, with `resolve`. Fact remains that in chrome, without the `await` before `resolve()` (exported `resolve` to `shoot`) only the first one actually resolves, which kinda debunks your theory. Also, I do not want `Promises.all()` I want to start the second one only after the first one was fired. The question is about the different in behavior. But @Ry- already nailed it

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've edited and made the `let shot =...` also async so it will not confuse anyone else.

Comment: You're creating a race condition between two separate `await` statements, yet you need it to work in one specific order for it to actually do what you want.  It's no wonder that it might work differently in different event loop or promise implementations.  Write code that doesn't depend upon a race condition and it will work consistently.

Comment: @Paulpro - There's zero reason to use a `while()` loop like this that relies on `await` to create a new promise with a new `resolve()`.  That's the weird part of the code and, in fact, what makes it bad code that doesn't run properly everywhere because it relies on unspecified implementation details/race conditions for ordering.  No matter what problem you're trying to solve, there are better ways to code it than this.  This is bad code and the proof is that it relies on unspecified implementation details of the Javascript engine in order to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `resolve()` is not async

And calling `resolve()` (via `shoot()`) does not immediately triggers the related `await` (in the loop) - but instead queues up the event. Adding `async`/`await` gives chance to the event loop to wake up and consume the queue. In chrome `await` alone is enough and in node `await` needs to be coupled with actual `async` function. This kind of synchronization of tasks in not reliable and there are chances of calling the same `resolve()` twice.

### This is an example of what NOT to do in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is relying on a somewhat obscure timing issue involving `await` of a constant (a non-promise).  That timing issue apparently does not behave the same in the two environments you have tested.

Each await `shoot(n)` is really just doing `await resolve(n)` which is not awaiting a promise. It's awaiting `undefined` since `resolve()` has no return value.

So, you're apparently seeing an implementation difference in event loop and promise implementation when you await a non-promise. You are apparently expecting `await resolve()` to somehow be asynchronous and allow your `while()` loop to run before running the next `await shoot(n)`, but I'm not aware of a language requirement to do that and even if there is, it's an implementation detail that you probably should not write code that relies on.

I think it's basically just bad code design that relies on micro-details of scheduling of two jobs that are enqueued at about the same time.  It's always safer to write the code in a way that enforces the proper sequencing rather than relying on micro-details of scheduler implementation - even if these details are in the specification and certainly if they are not.

node.js is perhaps more optimized or buggy (I don't know which) to not go back to the event loop when doing `await` on a constant.  Or, if it does go back to the event loop, it goes in a prioritized fashion that keeps the current chain of code executing rather than letting other promises go next.  In any case, for this code to work, it has to rely on some `await someConstant` behavior that isn't the same everywhere.

Wrapping `resolve()` forces the interpreter to go back to the event loop after each `await shoot(n)` because it is actually now awaiting a promise which gives the `while()` loop a chance to run and fill `shoot` with a new value before the next `shoot(n)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a Node 10 (possible) bug or (probable) outdated behaviour* in the implementation of promises. According to [the ECMAScript spec at the time of this writing](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#await), in

```
await shoot(1);
```

1. `shoot(1)` fulfills the promise created with `new Promise()`, which enqueues a job for each reaction in that promise’s fulfill reactions
2. `await undefined` (what `shoot(1)` returns) enqueues a job to continue after this statement, because `undefined` is converted to a fulfilled promise

The reaction in the promise’s fulfill reactions corresponding to the `await` in the first IIFE was added by [PerformPromiseThen](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen) and it doesn’t involve any other jobs; it just continues inside that IIFE immediately.

In short, the next `shoot = resolve` should always run before execution continues after `await shoot(n)`. The Node 12/current Chrome result is correct.

Normally, you shouldn’t come across this type of bug anyway: as I mentioned in the comments, relying on operations creating specific numbers of jobs/taking specific numbers of microticks for synchronization is bad design. If you wanted a sort of stream where each `shoot()` call always produces a loop iteration (even without the misleading `await`), something like this would be better:

```
let available;

(async () => {
  let queue = new Queue();

  while (true) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      available = value => {
        resolve();
        queue.enqueue(value);
      };
    });

    available = null;  // just an assertion, pretty much

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
      let value = queue.dequeue();

      // process value
    }
  }
})();

shoot(1);
shoot(2);
shoot(3);
```

with an appropriate queue implementation. (Then you could look to async iterators to make consuming the queue neat.)

<sub>* not sure of the exact history here. fairly certain the ES spec used to reference microtasks, but they’re jobs now. current stable firefox matches node 10. `await` may take less time than it used to. this kind of thing is the reason for the following advice.</sub>